# Create new tokens for vs code semantic highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

How can I create a new legend of tokens for VS code semantic highlighting?

This is the current list available as tokens: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#standard-token-types-and-modifiers

Additionally, this is the API used:

```js
const tokenTypes = ['class', 'interface', 'enum', 'function', 'variable'];
const tokenModifiers = ['declaration', 'documentation'];
const legend = new vscode.SemanticTokensLegend(tokenTypes, tokenModifiers);

const provider: vscode.DocumentSemanticTokensProvider = {
  provideDocumentSemanticTokens(
    document: vscode.TextDocument
  ): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.SemanticTokens> {
    // analyze the document and return semantic tokens

    const tokensBuilder = new vscode.SemanticTokensBuilder(legend);
    // on line 1, characters 1-5 are a class declaration
    tokensBuilder.push(
      new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(1, 1), new vscode.Position(1, 5)),
      'class',
      ['declaration']
    );
    return tokensBuilder.build();
  }
};

const selector = { language: 'java', scheme: 'file' }; // register for all Java documents from the local file system

vscode.languages.registerDocumentSemanticTokensProvider(selector, provider, legend);
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked the people on https://github.com/microsoft/language-server-protocol this question. The answer is that you can't define new types and modifiers--even though some programming languages do not fit into this classification scheme.

For example, a language server for a formal parser generator grammar like `Antlr4` contains lexer and parser symbols. That has hardly anything to do with `class`, `variable`, etc., or modifiers `static`, `readonly`, etc.

I tried to propose an arbitrary list of names for classification but was rejected because, I think, there is additional functionality that these classifiers denote. So, you will need to reuse what the client supports, a list you get on initialization, and a subset you return from the server.

For semantic highlighting, it "works". I do this for [my "universal language VSCode extension"](https://github.com/kaby76/uni-vscode), which takes a formal grammar, a list of classes, and XPath classifers to identify tokens in the input for semantic highlighting.

Comment: What do you mean by reuse? And did you have to convert your Antlr grammar to textmate to use the highlighting?

Comment: In the [Initialize request](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-current/#initialize), the client will send a list of supported token types. You must choose from this list tokentypes you want to use, returning a list of token types you plan on using. You can't just return a list of any string values, it must be what the client supports. A grammar has "nonterminal"s and "terminal"s. So, "class" and "variable" are meaningless for a grammar file. But to do sem highl'ng you must repurpose a "class" (and other tokentypes) for a nonterminal and terminal.

Comment: Textmate is not used whatsoever. The grammar serves as definition for the parse in the LSP server. After parsing, XPath2 expressions are evaluated on the parse tree to compute the results for the [Semantic Tokens request](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-17/#textDocument_semanticTokens). The XPath expressions identify what leaf nodes in the parse tree are of what semantic highlighting tokentype.

Comment: After re-reading your question, I realize that you are using a different api for semantic highlighting than I. But I think the same constraint applies: you need to use the token types the editor supports. In my LSP solution, I don't create a tmLanguage file because LSP directly queries all symbols for highlighting, which I provide from a parse tree.

Comment: Ok, yeah I'll switch over to a LSP instead of specifying my entire grammar in a tm since that will allow me to add the validation. additionally, can you explain how you provided the symbols from a parse tree to the LSP? I saw you wrote a blog post about my previous question, but I'm having trouble understanding how to dynamically send the grammar for the LSP to utilize